# Por que colocar COMMIT no final do script utilizando o banco de dados Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

Por que no banco de dados Firebird tudo que faço, inclusive criar tabelas é preciso no final do script dar um comando `COMMIT`?

Comment: Qual o problema de ter que dar um `COMMIT`?

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta:**

O comando `COMMIT` no final do script garante que todas as instruções colocadas acima dele serão executadas após a execução desse comando. A utilização desse comando pode evitar inconsistência dos dados caso algum comando no meio do script falhar.

Comment: Tem como desativar isso? No MySQL por exemplo, não é necessário.....

Comment: O MySQL não é transacional.

Answer (score 1):

O Firebird é um banco de dados **transacional**. Quer dizer que tudo é executado dentro de uma [transação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

`Commit` confirma as alterações feitas no contexto de uma transação.

`RollBack` faz o inverso, desfazendo as alterações no contexto de uma transação.